# How can I tell why a servlet filter has been invoked

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

In the servlet 2.4 spec you can define dispatchers in the filter config [REQUEST | FORWARD | ERROR | INCLUDE].

When the filter is invoked, how can I tell from which condition it was invoked from i.e. how can I tell if it was a request or an include or a forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"javax.servlet.*"` request attributes [contain information](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/webapp/faq.xtp) about the conditions that led to the filter being invoked.

Comment: Good info, but there is this exception:

    If getNamedDispatcher() is used to obtain a dispatcher to do the include() or forward(), no attributes are set.  

Also, is this resin specific?